# more like this search is not working on field in list object

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

this is the mapping of my index  i am searching on payload nested field category

```
{
   "mappings": {
      "date_detection": false,
      "properties": {
         "@class": {
            "type": "keyword"
         },       
         "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
               "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
               }
            }
         },
         "payload": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
               "@class": {
                  "type": "keyword"
               },
             
                     "description": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     
                    
                     "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "category": {
                  "type": "keyword"
               },
              
               "value": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my index mapping, Whenever i try to search object with more like this query in elasticsearch , it does not return any object,

**I am searching on list of object
**
the queries are

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [
        "payload.category"
      ],
      "like": [
        "ASSEST"
      ],
    
      "min_term_freq": 1,
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  }
}
```

It does not return any object but the values are present in elastic search

I just want to search similar object values present in elastic search thorough more like this query

But the Payload is actually list of objects which has filed category, i need to find similar objects according to it

Answer (score 0):

For nested fields use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

```
GET <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "payload",
      "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "payload.category"
          ],
          "like": [
            "assest doc"
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "max_query_terms": 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also look for min_doc_freq

> The minimum document frequency below which the terms will be ignored from the input document. Defaults to 5.

If you have less than 5 matching documents set "min_doc_freq" to 1